# Numpy 2D spatial mask to be filled with specific values from a 2D array to form a 3D structure

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I'm quite new to programming in general, but I could not figure this problem out until now.

I've got a two-dimensional numpy array `mask`, lets say `mask.shape is (3800,3500)`which is filled with 0s and 1s representing a spatial resolution of a 2D image, where a 1 represents a visible pixel and 0 represents background.
I've got a second two-dimensional array `data` of `data.shape is (909,x)` where `x` is exactly the amount of 1s in the first array. I now want to replace each 1 in the first array with a vector of length `909` from the second array. Resulting in a final 3D array of `shape(3800,3500,909)` which is basically a 2D x by y image where select pixels have a spectrum of 909 values in z direction.

I tried

```
mask_vector = mask.flatten
ones = np.ones((909,1))
mask_909 = mask_vector.dot(ones) #results in a 13300000 by 909 2d array
count = 0
for i in mask_vector:
    if i == 1:
        mask_909[i,:] = data[:,count]
        count += 1

result = mask_909.reshape((3800,3500,909))
```

This results in a viable 3D array giving a 2D picture when doing `plt.imshow(result.mean(axis=2))`
But the values are still only 1s and 0s not the wanted spectral data in z direction.
I also tried using `np.where` but broadcasting fails as the two 2D arrays have clearly different shapes.
Has anybody got a solution? I am sure that there must be an easy way...

Comment: What should contain the third dimension for background pixels (0s)?

Comment: Additional zeros. Basically I do not care about the 0 pixels. They can get 909 additional zeros in the third dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you simply need to use `np.where` to locate the 1s in your `mask` array. Then initialize your `result` array to zero and replace the third dimension with your data using the outputs of `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

m, n, k = 380, 350, 91
mask = np.round(np.random.rand(m, n))
x = np.sum(mask == 1)
data = np.random.rand(k, x)

result = np.zeros((m, n, k))
row, col = np.where(mask == 1)
result[row,col] = data.transpose()
```